# java.io.FileNotFoundException by using play dist

Tags: java, scala, logging, playframework, log4j

The below code works fine when I start project with `play start`

```
object LogFile {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  private var fileInput = new FileInputStream("./conf/log4j.properties");
  private val properties = new Properties
  properties.load(fileInput);

  def test(head: String, data: String) {
    System.setProperty("my.log", "scala.txt")
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties)
    val log = Logger.getLogger(head)
    log.error(data)
  }
}
```

but when I am using `sudo /home/ubuntu/play/play dist`
and run that I got:

```
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error:   
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./conf/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Scala 2.10 with play framework 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the Log4j Properties file

```
./conf/log4j.properties
```

You're probably missing the file:

```
/home/ubuntu/project/conf/log4j.properties
```

`sudo` command changes the user that you are executing as. So the new user possibly has different environment variables.

note: `project`  is application name.

Also, you're using a relative path `./conf/log4j.properties`, the root of which will be resolved at runtime based on the home directory that you are executing in. 
Possible solutions:

1) Don't use a relative path, rather use an absolute path

2) Change the home directory in the profile of the user that you are executing
    your application as ( root user?)

3) Copy the missing file to the directory where your application is looking for the file

Comment: Because your home directory that you're running in is different when you use sudo

Comment: `/home/ubuntu/Project/conf/log4j.properties`